# vb.net change reference in .vbproj file to user's local path

Tags: vb.net, reference

I want to know how to change reference in .vbproj file to user's local path since different user's project folder is different.

For example, A reference in .vbproj file is:

```
    <Reference Include="Spire.Common, Version=1.2.43.7035, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
       <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
       HintPath>C:\Users\Maple\AppData\Local\Temp\DeskApp\DeskApp\bin\Debug\Spire.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Which Maple is my local user name, I want it change to:

```
C:\Users\**UserName**\AppData\Local\Temp\DeskApp\DeskApp\bin\Debug\Spire.Common.dll
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ${env:username}
```

It would point to the windows username.

Comment: Hi JLILI, I can get the local user name, but I don't know how to use it in the .vbproj file, thanks